# Safe to bottle IPA with higher FG than expected?

Tags: fermentation, bottling, final-gravity

The expected FG from my receipt was supposed to be 1014, but it has been stable at 1020 for about 3 weeks now. The wort has been on the fermentation tank for about 4 weeks, it reached 1020 after 1 week and has been stable since.

The temperature in the room was a bit lower than I first thought, but probably not too low. It has been around 18'C (65'F) all weeks.

As I smell the wort, it has a really strong smell that attacks my nose! Kind of like Ammonium bicarbonate, but not as strong.

Is it safe for me bottle this IPA now? If it is needed, the recipe is here:

http://www.brewtoad.com/recipes/kontra-smash-ipa

Edit: Already bottled it, but added a bit more sugar than first planned. Ended up with 8.5 grams per litre. Would this be okay?

Comment: That burn you get when you smelled it was likely just CO2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've bottled it also with extra sugar, I think you should at least take precautions for exploding bottles. For example, placing the bottles in a water bath (not completely covered, water level just below the caps.)

This will help absorb rapid temperature swings and also absorb the energy from any explosions. If you also have something to cover the bottles with - a large plastic box, tarpaulin etc.. that will also be worth while.

It's not possible for anyone here to say if your bottles are safe. It really depends upon if there were more fermentables still in the wort. A [forced fermentation test](http://www.winning-homebrew.com/forced-fermentation-test.html) can tell you that. But since it's too late for that, best to just play it safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will take precautions. Is it also possible to take a look at the caps every once in a while to see if they start popping?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie, but have a few batches of IPA behind me. My batches were suppose to finish around 1.014, but all were 1.020 and they were fine, primed with 5oz of corn sugar for the 5 gallon batch.  Don't know about the smell though, mine smelled and tasted like beer.

Comment: Thanks. The smell of the beer itself is quite good and hoppy.